# Running tomcat with -server JVM option

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, jvm

I am testing my tomcat server 4, with -server jvm option. My JDK is 1.5 on FreeBSD.

I don't see any noticable difference or any issues.  If I am to turn this option on on my prod systems, what kind of improvement can I expect and what kind of issues should I lookout for?

I have read [What's the effect of -server option for the HotSpot JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459548/whats-the-effect-of-server-option-for-the-hotspot-jvm), but it does not discuss this in detail.

Comment: Suggestion: use tomcat 6 and JDK 6.

Comment: @Harry Joy - I wish I could :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite possible that the JVM was already running in server mode.  For JDK 5/6 on Linux, the JVM will default to server-mode on a server-class machine:

> *"[...] the definition of a server-class machine is one with at least 2 CPUs and at least 2GB of physical memory. "*

This is documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/server-class.html) (and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html) for Java 6).

It is not spelled out what happens on FreeBsd, but I expect that it is the FreeBsd JVMs are server-mode-only or that they defaults to server-mode on a server-class machine as with Linux.

Comment: I am on JDK 1.5. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/ergo5-140223.html says that JVM by default is in server mode for server class machines since 1.5. So I need not explicitly turn it on I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that modern JVM can "autodetect" a server-like machine. So if you do not specify `-server` or `-client`, a JVM1.5+ will choose the best method - and it simply may be that it will run in server mode even if you do not use the attribute.

In that case, you may notice a difference if you start the JVM with the `-client` option.

**Reference**

- [Server-Class Machine Detection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

First difference that server mode does is turns on Parallel GC, it is a throughput garbage collector, recommended for multi-core machines. In general, it will give you shorter delays for garbage collection.

Second, server mode will use more aggressive optimizations in the JIT.

I think server mode is a must have on production machine.

I'd recommend you to switch to 1.6 JVM, since it has better implementations of the gc's and is better optimized.

Answer (score 0):

The [OTN website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#compiler_types) discusses the difference. We seldom use the default arguments (GC collection algorithms, heap sizes, etc.) in any of our production systems so it doesn't provide much of a boost.

There aren't any specific things you need to lookout for after implementing this argument but if you see a difference between -server and -client, the JIT compiler is always a good place to start.

Answer (score -2):

you will notice the difference in long term due to different garbage collection and other parameters.

Comment: Ermm ... he doesn't.  That's what his question is about.